# non ascii letters inside js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a list that constains hebrew letters and for some reason it translates it to the following:

```
(18) ['��� �����', '���� �����', '���� �����', '��� �����', '���� ����', '��� �����', '��� ����', '���� �������', '������ ���', '���� ���', '�� ������', '��� �� ����', '��� �����', '��� ������', '��� ����', '���� ���', '��� �������', '���� ���']
```

When I write my code is a seperate js file thats the translation but when I write it directly to my html file, it works just fine.

I use vscode as my editor, if it has anything to do with it.

I tried to make a list of hebrew names but the browser couldn't read and therefore couldn't manipulate the list.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: More important than the editor is which encoding it uses for the file, and how that differs from the `Content-Type` HTTP header that your web server is sending. Show us the server configuration please.

Comment: To add to Bergi's comment, you might want to investigate the `charset` attribute of your `<script>` tag.

Comment: Make sure to save the file in unicode